# Sorting MySQL text Column with numbers

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have stored these texts in MySQL table column like this

```
    Hello, Your Order Id is 3458
    Sir, Your Order Id is 4833 
    With reference to the booking, your order Id is 4324
```

How can I sort this column according to Order IDs ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the order ID would always be the *last* word in the column string, you could try:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ' ', -1) AS UNSIGNED);
```

If the order could appear anywhere, then it gets more tricky.  If you are using MySQL 8+, then `REGEXP_REPLACE` comes in handy:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '^.*(?i)your order id is ([0-9]+).*', '$1') AS UNSIGNED);
```

### Demo